# How to mount the same directory to multiple containers in a pod

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running multiple containers in a pod. I have a persistence volume and mounting the same directories to containers.

My requirement is:

mount /opt/app/logs/app.log to container A where application writes data to **app.log**

mount /opt/app/logs/app.log to container B to read data back from **app.log**

```
- container-A
  image: nginx
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /opt/app/logs/ => container A is writing data here to **app.log** file
    name: data
- container-B
  image: busybox
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /opt/app/logs/ => container B read data from **app.log** 
    name: data
```

The issue I'm facing is - when I mount the same directory **/opt/app/logs/** to container-B, I'm not seeing the **app.log** file.

Can someone help me with this, please? This can be achievable but I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: probably container B mount happens after container A moint, so it overwrites the content with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirements, you need something like below:

```
- container-A
  image: nginx
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /opt/app/logs
    name: data
- container-B
  image: busybox
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /opt/app/logs 
    name: data
```

Your application running on container-A will create or write files on the given path(/opt/app/logs) say app.log file. Then from container-B you'll find app.log file in the given path (/opt/app/logs). You can use any path here.

In your given spec you actually tried to mount a directory in a file(app.log). I think that's creating the issue.

**Update-1:**
Here I give a full yaml file from a working example. You can do it by yourself to see how things work.

1. kubectl exec -ti test-pd -c test-container sh
2. go to /test-path1
3. create some file using touch command. say "touch a.txt"
4. exit from test-container
5. kubectl exec -ti test-pd -c test sh
6. go to /test-path2
7. you will find a.txt file here.

pvc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: 
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-path1
      name: test-volume
  - image: pkbhowmick/go-rest-api:2.0.1 #my-rest-api-server                    
    name: test
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-path2
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: test-pv-claim
```

Comment: I did the same way that you mentioned. But container-B is not able to locate the app.log file.  when I do `ls -l /opt/app/logs`  it returns **0** files

Comment: Are you using hostPath in your volume mounts?

Comment: No, I'm using persistence volumes.

Comment: I have given an working example using my local kind cluster. Hope you'll find the issue in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your example. What I noticed in container-A is that the directory has read-write permissions but owned by a non-root user. whereas in container-B it shows the same directory with root user.  Is this causing the app.log file is not available in container-B.

Answer (score 0):

From your post it seems you‘re having two separate paths.
Conatainer B ist mounted to /opt/app/logs/logs.

Answer (score 0):

Have different file names for each of your containers and also fix the mount path from the container config. Please use this as an example :-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /data
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```